# NSJSONSerialization: treating special characters properly

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa

I want to use online data from a JSON file. It's currently working, but when I use special characters it shows "null". Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://belesios.com/burc/koc2.php"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", json);
NSString *ciktiText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", json];
[kocLabel setText:ciktiText];
```

For example, if my file contains ç or ü, null is returned. What do I need to do?

Comment: First thing you should do is to print the error. - Does the server send the JSON data in UTF-8?

Comment: No, the first thing is writing in proper English and not abusing tags. Posting the error message helps, but it's only the second thing to do.

Comment: If the character code makes it into a NSString without "damage" then any proper JSON serializer/parser should handle it.  It's critical, however, that the data not be corrupted in data transmission.  You'd need to give us a more specific example of what you believe you're receiving and what you believe it's being translated as to begin to debug this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this method to find out what encoding is used when data is pulled from server:

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *jsonString =[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
if (error)
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
```

You should check encoding of data returned by the server. Your code is correct but you should add some check if error != nil then don't execute and display or log that.

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"abc\":\"ç or ü\"}";
NSDictionary *jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSLog(@"Output: %@", jsonObj);
```

**Output: { abc = "\U00e7 or \U00fc"; }** This is how your server response should look like with encoded char if you use Fiddler or some other software to print raw response.

Currently your data looks like where as UTF8 encoded chars should be like **\U00e7** = ç
[image]

Comment: Why should this work better? Your code converts the server response to a NSString and then back to NSData, there is no difference to using `dataWithContentsOfURL` directly.

Comment: @MartinR Default encoding is NSASCIIEncoding but to have the specials chars mentioned in the question one need UTF8 and if i am not wrong there is no direct method to load data in specific encoding. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL` loads the server response without any conversion. Your code converts the server response (interpreted as UTF-8) to a NSString and back to NSData. If the server sends UTF-8, there is no difference in the result. If the server does not send UTF-8, your code will not convert it to UTF-8.

Comment: this is my php file http://belesios.com/burc/koc2.php. if i delete special characters it work well. @SAPLogix i try your code but it give errors.

Comment: @user2100393 Your data is not properly encoded if u try the first method to see the encoding used it tell u that it wasn't able to decode it check your database for encoding or your php page. I update the code i wrote in the answer it had slight issue but it should be fine now and will not crash.

Comment: thnks @SAPLogix. how can i use online data which have special character ? i will use this data for textview. json, xml or any ?

Comment: @user2100393 You can use it anywhere are long your encoding is correct it won't be a problem.